# Eclipse Juno error when using console view in java browsing perspective

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno. When I am in the 'Java Browsing' perspective, if I have a Console view opened and I click on it, and then I click again on any other part of the 'Java browsing' perspective, I get an error *An error has occurred. See error log for more details. 4*. And this is the stack trace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2012-11-26 13:53:14.900
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table._getItem(Table.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table._getItem(Table.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.indexOf(Table.java:3010)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem.setText(TableItem.java:1214)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerRow.setText(TableViewerRow.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell.setText(ViewerCell.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2167)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.internalUpdate(StructuredViewer.java:2150)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2089)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.update(ColumnViewer.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:2033)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(StructuredViewer.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTableViewer.handleLabelProviderChanged(ProblemTableViewer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$1.labelProviderChanged(ContentViewer.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider$1.run(BaseLabelProvider.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.BaseLabelProvider.fireLabelProviderChanged(BaseLabelProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider$1.labelProviderChanged(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager$1.run(DecoratorManager.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager.fireListener(DecoratorManager.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$3.runInUIThread(DecorationScheduler.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=292199

This seems to be an old SWT bug with a long history.
Rarely reproducable and even harder to fix. (yet)